# PowerShell regex and e.164 telephone numbers

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm looking for telephone numbers that have exactly 12 or 13 digits.

The following two regex work:

```
PS C:\Data\UMCP> $bla = [regex]'^(\+[3][9])?([0-9]\d{9})$'
PS C:\Data\UMCP> $twelv -match $bla
True
PS C:\Data\UMCP> $bla = [regex]'^(\+[3][9])?([0-9]\d{10})$'
PS C:\Data\UMCP> $thirt -match $bla
True
```

But

```
PS C:\Data\UMCP> $bla = [regex]'^(\+[3][9])?([0-9]\d{9} | ^\+[3][9])?([0-9]\d{10})$'
PS C:\Data\UMCP> $thirt -match $bla
True
PS C:\Data\UMCP> $twelv -match $bla
False
```

How should I use the `|` or?

Comment: Add `(?x)`  at the start of the pattern or remove the spaces around pipe. And enclose the pattern in between anchors with another group. Or use `^(\+[3][9])?([0-9]\d{9,10}$`

Comment: Can you please give an example? Removing the spaces around the pipe didn't change anything. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a string matching this pattern: `+39` is optional at the start, then 10 or 11 digits? Then you can use `^(\+39)?[0-9]{10,11}$`. You do not need the alternation operator `|` then.

Comment: Your regex with a pipe: `'^(?:(?:\+[3][9])?[0-9]\d{9}|(?:\+[3][9])?[0-9]\d{10})$'`

Answer (score 1):

You have whitespaces around the pipe, and that whitespace matters. To make some whitespace (like this, e.g.) a "formatting whitespace", add `(?x)` `IgnorePatternWhitespace` inline modifier to the start of the pattern.

Also, you should be careful with unescaped parentheses, they make groups and must be paired.

Your fixed pattern could look like

```
'^(?:(?:\+[3][9])?[0-9]\d{9}|(?:\+[3][9])?[0-9]\d{10})$'
  |   |--OPT.GR.-|          | |-OPT.GR.--|           |
  |---------- BRANCH 1------|-------- BRANCH 2-------|
```

See how the groups are created: the outer parentheses create a group so that `^` and `$` could be applied to both alternative branches, and the inner ones are used to form an optional group (with the `?` quantifier after them).

If you have a string matching this pattern:

- An optional `+39` at the start
- 10 or 11 digits up to the end of string

Use

```
^(?:\+39)?[0-9]{10,11}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qT8pV1/1)

Comment: I would definitely go for `{10,11}`, +1

Comment: Sure, I would, too. Backtracking is minimal then. I did not dwell on all details here, but I should perhaps note that `\d` is not equal to `[0-9]` in .NET regex flavor where `\d` matches all Unicode digits. So, to match digits from 0 till 9 one needs to use a safer character class `[0-9]`.